# Method for changing an existing color OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, rgb, lwjgl, bytebuffer

With a method like `glColor4f(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);`, it sets the values to whatever parameters one puts in. However, what I would like to do is only slightly change a color. Is there any existing OpenGL method that will add or subtract its parameters to the existing colors it has?

The only other way of doing this that I can come up with is first getting its color values, then editing those how I want to, and finally sending them back with `glColor4f()`.

So, in closing, I would like to know if there is either a method for editing existing RGBA, or at least retrieving an existing RGBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can get the last value set with `glColor4f` by using `glGet` with `GL_CURRENT_COLOR`, but I wouldn't recommend it; `glGet` operations are generally bad for your performance, so try not to do it too often.

A better idea would be to maintain a local copy of the last value you sent to `glColor4f`, so that you have the data client-side instead of having to request it from the opengl driver.

<strike>There's no way to add or subtract from the current color that I'm aware of.</strike>

Edit: Actually I just looked up and see this function called [`glSecondaryColor`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glSecondaryColor.xml) which may do what you want. You can supply a second RBG color, and then enable GL_COLOR_SUM, and the two colors get added together.

Comment: This is perfect, but it doesn't work with negative parameters for subtracting, such as `glSecondaryColor3d(0,-15/255d,0)`. However, I've played around with it and I'm pretty sure I can achieve the same effect by doing `glSecondaryColor3d(15/255d,0,15/255d)`. Regardless, this is exactly what I was searching for, so thanks.

Comment: Really? According to the man page you should be able to supply a negative color. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glSecondaryColor.xml @GlassZee

Comment: Yea, it's not showing up as a difference when you enter negatives. Quite a shame, really. But I came up with an even better solution to the problem-- starting with R, G, and B a bit high, then slowly lowering G to 0. It's literally the "same difference". Just gotta darken the original textures by the amount you add onto them.